# Subscribe on bool state using Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an `IObservable<bool>` and I want to be notified when the last `n` items are set to true.

For that I'm trying things like:

```
MyBool.Buffer(10).SelectMany(x => x).All(x => x).Subscribe(x => /*do something*/);
```

But it only fires once; it seems like the `OnCompleted` is fired somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are effectively buffering and flattening your observable. Calling `.Buffer(10).SelectMany(x => x)` is like a non-operation as it emits what ever went in.

What you need to do is more like this:

```
    MyBool
        .Buffer(10, 1)
        .Select(xs => xs.All(x => x))
        .Where(x => x);
```

I assumed you wanted to know whenever there are 10 trues in a row, so that if there are 11 you are notified twice.

---

The reason behind `Buffer(10, 1)` is the way `Buffer` works - this gives a buffer of `10` elements and moves along by `1`. If I did `Buffer(10)` I would get 10 elements and move along by ten.

If I did `Observable.Range(0, 5).Buffer(3)` I get `{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4}`, but if I did `Observable.Range(0, 5).Buffer(3, 1)` I get `{0, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4}, {4}`.

If you want to know when a `false` comes thru after the `trues` then try this:

```
MyBool
        .Buffer(3, 1)
        .Select(xs => xs.All(x => x))
        .Buffer(2, 1)
        .Where(x => x[0] || x[1]);
```

This gives these possible combinations:

[image: results]

Comment: This actually worked, could you please explain what is the point of skipping `1` in buffer?

Comment: I am struggling now to implement notification when MyBool is set to false after those 10 trues in a row. Do I need another IObservable for that and combine somehow with the current (`MyBool`)?

Comment: @Sturm - I've added more detail.